# Find specific word in string and echo that specific word

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a variable has a number that starts with >> i.e., >>12345 and then separate that number into a different variable.

For example:

```
$my_string = "
>>12345

Hello this is an example string.
";
```

I'd like to store the '>>12345' in the database as a separate variable. Similar to image boards.

Comment: `regexp` is what you need. see example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555905/how-to-match-exactly-3-digits-in-phps-preg-match. you can validate your regexp sintax here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done with a regular expression:

```
<?php

$my_string = "
>>12345

Hello this is an example string.
";
preg_match("/(>>\d+)/", $my_string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

The Regex looks for >>followed by any number of numeric digits, then captures that group into the `$matches` array.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/cKE6J